# How return multiple values with SOAP in Java (javax.jws)

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm using Java 8 and Eclipse with TomCat 8.
I want to write a SOAP web service wich return 3 integer with each of them a different field name (id, key and value) like this :

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getArrResponse xmlns="http://DefaultNamespace">
         <id>1</id>
         <key>1</key>
         <value>2</value>
      </getArrResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I wrote this SOAP server in Java and it works :

```
    @WebService()
public class MyWebService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "printName")
    public String printName(@WebParam(name = "userName") String userName) {

        return "hello " + userName;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public int[] getArr() {
        int[] i = { 1, 1, 2};
        return i;
    }
}
```

it returns :

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getArrResponse xmlns="http://DefaultNamespace">
         <getArrReturn>1</getArrReturn>
         <getArrReturn>1</getArrReturn>
         <getArrReturn>2</getArrReturn>
      </getArrResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I don't know and I don't found how change the filed name from *getArrReturn* to *id* or *key*

Edit : 
I tried to return a HashTable object, and it returned :

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getArrResponse xmlns="http://DefaultNamespace">
         <getArrReturn>
            <item xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns="">
               <key xsi:type="xsd:string">key</key>
               <value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</value>
            </item>
            <item xmlns="">
               <key xsi:type="xsd:string">value</key>
               <value xsi:type="xsd:int">2</value>
            </item>
            <item xmlns="">
               <key xsi:type="xsd:string">id</key>
               <value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</value>
            </item>
         </getArrReturn>
      </getArrResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: have you thought of returning a custom object instead of an array?

Comment: I tried to return a HashTable. But what do you mean about a "custom object" ?

Comment: create a class with 3 integer fields (key,value,id) and return an object of this class

Comment: I doesn't work, i have an error (Return is the name of my object) :   java.io.IOException: MapSerializer:  Return is not a map

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create and return a class with JAXB annotations like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "context",
    "key",
    "value"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "getArrResponse")
public class GetArrResponse implements Serializable
{
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "id", required = true)
    private int id;
    @XmlElement(name = "key", required = true)
    private int key;
    @XmlElement(name = "value", required = true)
    private int value;
}
```

Usually it is more convenient to generate such classes from XSD, consider this if you're going to create more complex service.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I have the still the same error when I want return a custom object "java.io.IOException: MapSerializer:  Return is not a map"  (Return is the name of my object) :/